# Can I get my iPhone to see the "Other Calendars" from Google Apps for domains Calendars?

Tags: iphone

Our office is using Google Apps.  I have it set up to sync calendars against Google, but none of my Other Calendars appear when I click the calendars button on the iPhone.  Is this possible?

I've tried the sync instructions, but navigating to google.com/sync from safari on the iPhone assumes you will log in with a Google account, not a Google apps account.

Comment: This question is probably obsolete today. Is it?

Comment: @ddaa I think you are probably right, but I don't know how to repro to see because I already have it set up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is possible:

> Okay, the Google instructions aren't what I would call stellar for this particular setup procedure but they are correct. It's as simple as going to m.google.com, then logging in if necessary, choosing iPhone, and finally choosing the Calendars you want to Sync with your iPhone. It worked for me for 2 Calendars. Hope this helps!
>
> 1. Complete Google's instructions
> 2. Open Safari on your iPhone
> 3. Navigate to m.google.com
> 4. Select 'Sync'
> 5. Select your device
> 6. Check the boxes next to the Calendars you want to sync (It will only let you choose 5 total, including the "US Holidays" one)
> 7. Click 'Save.'

via: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=3a0f6b239b1eadc5&hl=en

Comment: This link appears broken.

Comment: See the answer below "So it's 2017..." still works in 2021. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/302304/252596

Answer (score 25):

I [found the answer](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Apps/thread?tid=506244ab815d8dbe&hl=en)

"By default only your primary calendar will be synced to your device. You can sync additional calendars by visiting the following page from any web browser:

- https://www.google.com/calendar/iphoneselect
  (Google Apps users can go to https://www.google.com/calendar/hosted/your_domain/iphoneselect, replacing 'your_domain' with your actual domain name.)"

Comment: This is the correct answer, especially if you're looking to sync Google Apps calendars. I would note that the 'your_domain' part needs to be the full domain. If your domain is 'example.com' then replace 'your_domain' with 'example.com' and not just 'example'.

Answer (score 20):

So it's 2017, and the answer to your question has changed a bit, but it seems easier at least!

1. Make sure you're signed into your Google account in whatever browser you use, of course, and then go to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect. You should see a list of all of your calendars, including shared/other calendars, so simply check the calendars you would like to see on Apple's Calendars app.
2. Make sure your Google account has been added/registered on your iPhone/iPad/Mac, and that you have given the Google account access to Calendars.
3. Go to the Calendars app, and you should see the calendars you checked in Step 1 in the list of calendars. Make sure they are checked in order to see them on your main calendar.

Please let me know if anything needs clarification! Hope this helps.

Comment: It works for me!

Comment: Works for me too! @michael-pryor it would help future visitors if you mark this as best answer. Current best one didn't work for me and I almost miss this one.

Comment: Awesome, worked for me in 2020. Thank you very much.

Comment: Works for me in July 2021

Comment: Works for me in January 2023

Answer (score 1):

There are some pitfalls to getting your iPhone to sync up with the calendars you'd like, but it is possible.

Navigate Safari to [m.google.com/sync?hl=en](http://m.google.com/sync?hl=en). If Google complains, that your device is not supported, it's most likely because of your language settings. In that case, locate the link to change your language on the bottom of the page, and change it to `English (US)`. The link I've provided should do that automatically, but in case it doesn't, well, you know what to do.

Now you should see a list of mobile devices associated with your Google account. Pick the one whose settings you want to change.

You'll see a list with all your calendars. At the top of the page, you'll see how many calendars you'll be able to sync your phone with. Pick the calendars you'd like to sync, tap `Save`, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Full Google Calendar integration is possible. Once your Google calendar is sync-ed up using the iPhone settings, open Safari and go to m.google.com . Choose 'Sync' and Select your device. Then check the boxes next to the Calendars you want to sync.

For extra utility use [this Facebook calender export application](http://fbcal.com/) to unify all your calendars in one place (just be sure to set the time zone correctly when you create the FBcal for Google Calendar).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach, which avoids using the Google software: I subscribe to all my Google Calendars within iCal on my Mac, via Calendar -> Subscribe, which then syncs to my iPhone.

Answer (score -2):

If the issue is for your iphone go here:

http://carlsednaoui.com/post/55604535740/google-calendar-adding-other-calendars-to-your-iphone

It isn't necessary to do it on your mobile device.